# OOP Encapsulation Concept

Tags: oop, encapsulation

In an interview I have been asked this. Is this is an  example of Encapsulation?

```
class abc
{

}
```

I tried seeking for the answer from multiple books but couldn't find it.

Comment: The point here is that the class has no members and methods?

Comment: Can you give a clear and specific definition of "encapsulation"?

Comment: I can tell you for sure that it sounds like a pretty bad question.

Answer (score 2):

We would start talking about encapsulation when the following would happen:

- The class will have **members** and **methods** and therefore becomes *a collection of data and methods.*
- In this class we start **hiding** the data within, and **make it available** only through public methods

This technique is known as **encapsulation** because it seals the data (and internal methods) safely inside the "capsule" of the class, where it can be accessed only by trusted users (i.e., by the methods of the class).

Until no methods and members, I don't think we are talking about encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

If the class is empty, there is no information to be encapsulated, so no [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)#As_information_hiding_mechanism) here.

Answer (score 0):

No its not,

Encapsulation refers to the act of binding together data members and functions which manipulate them into a single entity.

Mostly they are bound into a class.

But the example here has to data members and functions to encapsulate, so it's not an Encapsulation